# Mysql : Algorithm to select most recent item per key in a history table

Tags: mysql

I'm facing an algorithmic problem.
I have a table, which is an history table that i didn't build. The table has this kind of structure :

id - file - comment date - comment - author

1 - 1 - 20180901 - hi - 2
2 - 1 - 20170901 - hello - 3
3 - 2 -  -  - 
4 - 2 - 20160504 - Hi everyone -4

Every file can have multiple comments, but i'd only like to select one row per file with the most recent comment recorded.

I tried a different set of combinaisons of group by, having, where, max... but couldn't manage to get the expected result.

I guess that it's just a trick to know but i don't...

Any help would be welcome !

Thank you
Vincent

Comment: If you have two "most recent" comments in the same file with the same date, which one should be shown? Any? All of them? The one with the higher id value?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Each comments are sorted with datetime and each one is separated by months usually so this may not be a problem. A turnaround would be highest ID as the comment ID is auto incremented :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with an Exclusion Join:

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.file, c1.comment_date, c1.comment, c1.author
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN comments c2
ON c2.file = c1.file AND c2.id > c1.id 
WHERE c2.id IS NULL
```

I'm using the `id` column to determine the most recent row per file instead of the `comment_date` column because there may be rows with duplicate `comment_date` values per file.

If you must use comment_date, then you can use this query that falls back to the `id` if there are duplicate dates:

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.file, c1.comment_date, c1.comment, c1.author
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN comments c2
ON c2.file = c1.file AND c2.comment_date > c1.comment_date AND c2.id > c1.id 
WHERE c2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: This sounds very good to me, I'll give it a try ASAP & think it'll help a lot. Thank you !

Comment: Quick feedback : Your suggestion worked very vey well, except that as I'm working on large datasets with non indexed common keys, it takes a very long time to run. My turnaround : instead of executing this on page loading, I'll use it as a cleaning request on data daily update : creating a temp table with only most recent comment per file. Thanks again !